# Hyperlinks to hypertargets in TOC when using XeTeX

Tags: table-of-contents, xetex, hyperlink

I am trying to set up my document such that every chapter title also serves as a hyperlink to the table of contents. In my actual document, the table of contents spans several pages, so I want these links to lead to the actual location of the chapter entry in the TOC.

I also am using XeTeX (XeLaTeX in Overleaf) as I want to use the CharisSIL font.

I created this minimally working example of what I am trying to do:

```latex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\let\oldchapter\chapter
% Handle star in chapter
\def\chapter{\@ifstar\starchapter\linkedchapter}
\def\starchapter{\oldchapter*}
% New linked chapter command
\newcommand{\linkedchapter}[2][\@empty]
{
\ifx#1\@empty \oldchapter[#2]{\hyperlink{toc.chapter.\thechapter}{#2}}
\else \oldchapter[#1]{\hyperlink{toc.chapter.\thechapter}{#2}}
\fi
 }
\makeatother

% Renew the contentsline command
\let\hypercontentsline=\contentsline
\renewcommand{\contentsline}[4]{\hypertarget{toc.#4}{}\hypercontentsline{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}%
}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
{
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\hypertarget{toc}{}}
  \tableofcontents
}

\chapter{Preface}

\mainmatter
\chapter{Ch1}
\chapter{Ch2}
\chapter{Ch3}

\backmatter
\chapter{Epilogue}

\end{document}
```

If I compile this using pdfLaTeX in Overleaf, it works, every chapter title (including the front and back matter ones) link to the TOC.

However, if I compile it using XeTeX (XeLaTeX), the Preface link doesn't work.

How can I fix this? Cheers!

Comment: the preface link doesn't work with pdflatex either. It is only not visible because the fall back is to go to the first page. The destination name of the unnumbered preface is `chapter*.2`,  and not `toc.chapter.0`. Use `\hyperlink{toc.\@currentHref}{#2}`  in your links. (Personally I don't think that this a good idea. I rarely want to go from a chapter title to the toc and I don't like it if too many areas on a page are active, that is problematic if you use a touch screen.)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer It works, thanks a lot! And yeah you're right, it might be a bit too cluttery so I'll see how I can avoid that.